# Accumulate changes in data frame in Shiny app in R

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I'm building a shiny app where i want a user to be able to write down a changes to data frame by pressing a button, and i want that changes to be stored and be available in data frame. For example:

```
    library("shiny")
    
    data <- as.data.frame(diamonds)
    data$comment <- NA
    
    toChange <- data
    
    ui <- fluidPage(
      selectInput(inputId = "cut", 
                  label = "Select Cut", 
                  choices = unique(diamonds$cut), 
                  selected = "Ideal"),
      actionButton(inputId = "price", 
                   label = "Write new price"),
      DTOutput("tabOut")
      
    )
    
    server <- function(input,session, output) {
     
       observeEvent(input$price, {
        toChange[toChange$cut == input$cut, "price"] <- toChange[toChange$cut == input$cut, "price"] * 3
        toChange[toChange$cut == input$cut, "comment"] <- paste0("updated: ", Sys.time())
        
        output$tabOut <- renderDT({
          toChange
        }, filter = "top")
      })
      
      observeEvent(req(input$price == 0), {
        output$tabOut <- renderDT({
          data
        }, filter = "top")
      })
      
      observeEvent(input$price, {
       
      })

    }
    
   shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

In this case, when i run the app and press the "Write new price" button, i'll have it only for the last selected choice in the "cut" selector. But I want it to keep als the values from the previous selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can store the changed dataset in `reactiveValues` and update it every time users click the button.

```r
library("shiny")
library(DT)
data <- as.data.frame(ggplot2::diamonds)
data$comment <- NA

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId = "cut", 
                label = "Select Cut", 
                choices = unique(ggplot2::diamonds$cut), 
                selected = "Ideal"),
    actionButton(inputId = "price", 
                 label = "Write new price"),
    DTOutput("tabOut")
    
)

server <- function(input,session, output) {
    
    toChange <- reactiveValues(df = data)
    observeEvent(input$price, {
        toChange$df[toChange$df$cut == input$cut, "price"] <- toChange$df[toChange$df$cut == input$cut, "price"] * 3
        toChange$df[toChange$df$cut == input$cut, "comment"] <- paste0("updated: ", Sys.time())
        
        output$tabOut <- renderDT({
            toChange$df
        }, filter = "top")
    })
    
    observeEvent(req(input$price == 0), {
        output$tabOut <- renderDT({
            data
        }, filter = "top")
    })
    
    
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```